# Point my applicationSettings to local IIS webservice

Tags: asp.net, iis

I would like to locate my web.config applicationSetting to my local IIS web service.

Right now it's connected to another server:

```
    <applicationSettings>
        <CertifikateArkiv.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="CertifikateArkiv_BUMSreportAsPDF_ReportCentralService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://tsrv3653/File/reportcentral.asmx</value>
          </setting>
        </CertifikateArkiv.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
```

Let's say I have my webservice on the directory "web sites" on the IIS manager.
How do I make the applicationSetting point to that local IIS instead of that server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use localhost for local site.

```
http://localhost/File/reportcentral.asmx
```